# discrete variables in fraction

Tags: statistics

I am looking for examples of discrete variable whose value is in fraction ONLY. I am told there are very few such examples.

I am not looking for variables with mixture of both whole numbers and fractions such as shoe size 3, 4, 5, 6.5, 7...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should look into things that are defined as ratios of 2 integers. A few examples:

- When you throw a fixed number of dices a fixed number of times: the probabilities of various events can only take on values of the form $m/N$ where $N$ is the (fixed) number of all possible outcomes.
- There are 4 tennis majors in each calendar year with each major entailing 7 matches, so the winning rate at majors within a calendar year for any particular athlete who plays at least 1 major match is a number $m/N$ where $1\leq N\leq 28$ and $0\leq m\leq N$.
- Actual birth rates, mortality rates, etc.

(I assumed you meant you were looking for examples of variables that could only take on rational values in $[0,1]$.)